# How to do Partition validation inside of partition of a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like as below
[image]

I need to add a new column called as "FLAG" which is look like as below

[image]

The logic behind the FLAG column is

1. Join_date<= sys_assignment then i need to give FLAG "Y" for the minimum sys_assignment date and remaining as "N" (ex: 101 and 103 records)
2. If join_date> sys_assignment (if any partition satisfy this condition, in this example 102 and 104 ) consider only those records (sub partition) and give FLAG as "Y" for the maximum value of sys_assignment and remaining all are "N" (The sub partitions are highlighted in THICK colors)

Please help me on this..!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT empid, join_date, sys_assignment, 
  IF((option AND min_flag) OR (NOT option AND NOT grp AND max_flag), 'Y', 'N') flag
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    join_date <= sys_assignment grp,  
    COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY empid) = COUNTIF(join_date <= sys_assignment) OVER(PARTITION BY empid) option,
    sys_assignment = MIN(sys_assignment) OVER(PARTITION BY empid, join_date <= sys_assignment) min_flag, 
    sys_assignment = MAX(sys_assignment) OVER(PARTITION BY empid, join_date > sys_assignment) max_flag
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

when applied to your sample data - above query produces below result (which looks to me exactly what is expected)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (partition by empid
                           order by (case when join_date < sys_assignment then 1 else 2 end),
                                    (case when join_date < sys_assignment then sys_assignment end) asc,
                                    (case when join_date < sys_assignment then NULL else sys_assignment end) desc
                          ) = 1
       ) as flag
from t;
```

The flag here is represented as a boolean rather than as character, which is more appropriate for BigQuery.

Comment: This query is giving me correct result for 1st condition but for second condition it is not considering sub partitions and giving me incorrect for 102 record

Comment: for 102, first i need to apply the condition if hire_date>sys_assigntime then we need to consider only those records and (in our case only 2 records) in which max time is "2019-03-21 13:21:05" as Y and remaining as "N", Boolean values are also fine for me.

Comment: @kalyan4uonly . . . There is no `hire_date` in your question.

Comment: i mean join_date, sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Probably could do it with partitioning, but I find it easier to read this way.
Look if there is no record with a higher sys_assignment to get the lowest.  Then look to see there is another record to No the single case.

Try this:

```
update mytable
set flag=case when not exists (select 'x' from mytable t where t.join_date=mytable.join_date and t.sys_assignment<mytable.sys_assignment) 
and exists (select 'x' from mytable t where t.join_date=mytable.join_date and t.sys_assignment>mytable.sys_assignment) 
then 'Y' else 'N' end
```